# PayPal With Automated Delivery For Digital Services

Tags: php, sql, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

I recently started a company, selling digital items. And I'm not too sure where I can start for automating the checkout process. I will need 4 custom variables: name, email, package, Textfield; from my customers. I will then send the digital item to their email.

I have currently set up, a PayPal button with two custom fields. I'm seeking for an easier solution maybe integrating a PayPal express check out with custom fields, but I'm not too savvy with PayPal's Api.

Any sort of guidance or code snippet examples will be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track.  I would recommend the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/).  This [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make the API calls very quick and easy.  There are [demo kits](https://www.angelleye.com/product-category/php-class-libraries/demo-kits/) available for it, too, but the samples it comes with may be enough for you to get going.

You can build your form however you want to gather whatever detail you need.  Save a record of that in your DB prior to sending the user over to PayPal.  This way you can include the record ID in the payment request to PayPal.

When the payment is completed you can use [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) to automatically process and deliver the purchase.  You can use that to generate and send custom email notifications with attachments, update your database, hit 3rd party web services, etc. automatically, in real-time.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, really helpful!!